# App works remotely but gives me database error locally

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I start working on a meteor app so I can start learning the framework. The application is supposed to store a number of geolocated objects in the database, and show the objects that are closest to the user at each time. Simple stuff.

The code that handles the data is the following

**Server side code**

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
Datum._ensureIndex({ location : "2dsphere" });
});

Meteor.methods({
  saveData : function(data){
    var insert = {
      'text' : data.text,
      'location': {
        longitude: data.location.coords.longitude,
        latitude:  data.location.coords.latitude
      },
      'submittedOn': new Date(),
      'submittedBy' : Meteor.userId()
  };
   var dataId = Datum.insert(insert);
   return dataId;
  }   
});

// This supposed to fetch the nearby data every time I call Datum.find({}) on the client
Meteor.publish('nearbyObjects', function(location){
return Datum.find({
    location: {
        $near:  [location.coords.longitude, location.coords.latitude], 
        $maxDistance: 5            
    }
});
});
```

**Common**

```
Datum = new Meteor.Collection("datum");
```

When I save my data it seems to work fine, but when I attempt to fetch it I see this error:

```
Exception in queued task: MongoError:
can't parse query (2dsphere): { $near: [ 23.72931, 37.983715 ], $maxDistance: 5 }
```

The weird thing is that when I deploy to my demo meteor server, the query works fine and returns results just fine. The same thing happens if I try to run the query by hand using the `meteor mongo` tool on each database. Has everyone stumbled on this issue?

I am running meteor `0.8.0`, and the `version()` command in mongodb returns `2.4.9` in all servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, you've not structured your location objects correctly. I can't remember but it looks like you're using the older notation for your coordinates which has since been deprecated. 2dsphere does not support the style you are using anymore.

Use this instead:

```
location: {
     type : "Point",
     coordinates : [ 23.72931, 37.983715 ]     
}
```

Then you can use this as a query:

```
return Datum.find({{
        $near : {
            $geometry : {
                type : "Point",
                coordinates : [ 23.72931, 37.983715 ]
            }
        },
        $maxDistance : 5
});
```

More details at the mongodb docs: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/

Comment: I see, I will test it after work and accept the answer then. But shouldn't it break on the demo server as well?

Comment: It depends on the data in the indexes. Its hard to say exactly, the error comes from mongodb, not really from meteor.